# Regex to match a particular word followed by another, along with a boundary identifier

Tags: python, regex, text

I am doing a regular expression matching in Python. I tried to follow some combinations but not working. I am entirely new to Regular expressions. My problem is, I am having a string as follows.

```
string = ''' World is moving towards a particular point'''
```

I want a solution to check if  word "towards" is present immediately after the word "moving" and if so, i want to select the rest of the line ( after 'towards' ) until it ends with a '.' or a '-'. I am newbie to this. Please provide some good suggestion.

Comment: What about `"World is moving towards me. And you."` - what exactly should be matched? Only `me.`? or the entire rest of the line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like

```
re.findall (r'(?<=moving towards )[^-.]*', string)
['a particular point']
```

- `(?<=moving towards )` look behind assertion. Asserts that the string is preceded by `moving towards`
- `[^-.]*` matches anything other than a `-` or `.`

---

**How it matches**

```
World is moving towards a particular point
                        |
     (?<=moving towards ) #checks if this position is presceded by moving towards 
                          #yes, hence proceeds with the rest of the regex pattern

World is moving towards a particular point
                        |
                      [^-.]

World is moving towards a particular point
                         |
                       [^-.] 

# and so on


World is moving towards a particular point
                                         |
                                       [^-.]
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/cG5cK5/1)

Comment: @user3116355 You are welcome :) Feel free to accpet any one of the answers you find usefull.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Thanks a lot :). Feels good when people appreciate you on new years !!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [negative-look around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) . but it work when you have `.` or `-` in your string  if you haven't you can use @nu11p01n73R 's answer .  :

```
>>> string = ''' World is moving towards a particular point.'''
>>> re.search(r'(?<=moving towards).*(?=\.|-)',string).group(0)
' a particular point'
```

`(?<=moving towards).*` is negative look-behind match all (.*) after `moving towards`

and `(?=\.|-)'` is negative look-behind that match all before (`\.|-`) that means `.` or `-`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/y7fYlK0ncNM3sFRA)

Comment: The alternation is wrongly scoped, the second dot should be escaped, and you'd need a lazy quantifier to make this work correctly...

Comment: @TimPietzcker yep , but OP says *until it ends with a '.' or a '-'.* and this make me confused

Comment: Hmm, an optional lookahead assertion may as well be removed entirely. It has no effect at all. Also, both your lookaround assertions are positive, not negative.

Comment: @Kasra - It is also working man. But could you explain this in brief.

Comment: @user3116355 yes pls give some min

Comment: @TimPietzcker no, without optional it raise `AttributeError:` as there is no `.` or `-` in his string !

Comment: That's certain, but your solution is wrong. Your regex is *no different* from `(?<=moving towards).*`.

Comment: You have a lookbehind and a lookahead, and they are both positive.

Comment: @Kasra - Hey. What if I have to match a word followed by a word, with multiple spaces .....?

Comment: @user3116355 where are the spaces ?

Comment: @Kasra I have posted it as a question now. Do i have to withdraw the question. Suppose i have a string "I love my    world". the word after "my" (here world) should be returned or find , regardless of the spaces.

Comment: @user3116355 i gave you an answer there ;)

Comment: @Kasra - Thanks a lot. I am struggling with regex. Cant follow a patter in generic way. Do you have any suggestions on good basic tutorial to start with ??

Comment: @user3116355 you're welcome http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html is very good place for learning regex !

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
str = ''' World is moving towards a particular point'''
match = re.search('moving towards\s+([^.-]+)', str)
if match:
   var = match.group(1)

Output >>> a particular point
```

regex debug link

```
https://www.regex101.com/r/wV7iC7/1
```

Answer (score 0):

To repeat the question, you want to check whether in the given `string` the word "moving" is followed by "towards". Here is a way to do this using the [parse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse) module:

```
import parse
string = "World is moving towards a particular point"

fmt = "moving {:w}"

result = parse.search(fmt, string)

assert result[0] == "towards"
```

Note that the `:w` format specification causes the result to match letters and underscores.